# Issue rendering collection data in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I want to render collection in handlebars precompiled templates,
`this.courses.fetch()` is working
handlebars view is rendering correctly...(only each loop not rendering collection data)

here is my code...

router.js

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
 routes: {
     'master/courses' : 'courses'
 },
initialize: function(){
    this.courses = new App.Collections.Courses();
     this.list = new App.Views.List( {collection: this.courses} );
},
courses: function() {
    $('#page').html(this.list.render().el);
}
 });

var app = new App.Router();

Backbone.history.start();
```

courses.js

```
App.Collections.Courses = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: App.Models.Course,
url: '/api/courses'
});
```

list.js

```
p.Views.List = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
},
render:function(){
    this.$el.html( Handlebars.templates.list(this.collection) );
    return this;
}
 });
```

list.handlebars

```
<h1>Courses</h1>

<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        {{#each models}}
        <td>{{attributes.id}}</td>
        <td>{{attributes.name}}</td>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
```

this is my first attempt on backbone project kindly suggest good practice also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see here the point where collection fetching is fired. The first line in your `courses` probably should be `this.collection.fetch({ reset: true });`

As I see in provided HTML structure, `each` should be before `tr` tag. Like this:

```
<h1>Courses</h1>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each models}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{attributes.id}}</td>
      <td>{{attributes.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```